# Creating new object placed in wrong thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt5, qthread

I have Qt5/C++ code that runs in a thread.  Main (thread #0) creates my new thread (thread #1), and there I created a new object ("hardware").

I would expect "hardware" object to live in thread #1, since it was created in code running in thread #1.  However, after much debugging my code below shows that "hardware" lives in thread #0.

```
// Running in thread #1
m_hardwarePtr = new hardware();
qDebug() << "Start HW FROM Thread" << this->thread() << this->thread()->objectName();   
qDebug() << "Start HW IN Thread" << m_hardwarePtr->thread() << m_hardwarePtr->thread()->objectName();
```

Why?  I supposed I could pass the QThread to the above code and then move "hardware" into thread #1 - but I shouldn't have to...should I?

Can someone explain why this is happening and the correct way to fix this?

UPDATE:

Based on comments I want to add that my code above is in a method called FROM thread #0.  When I changed my code to call the above method via a slot, it works as expected!

For the sake of others, I would like to accept an answer that explains (in the context of incorrectly calling the method directly from thread #0):

1. Why (when I called the code above) from Thread #0 did it report as running in thread #1
2. Why when I created a new thread in the above code didn't the new object ALSO run in thread #0

My problem is solved BTW, but I think a good explanation would help everyone.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].  Is the code shown executed from within the `run` method of the `QThread`?

Comment: Please don't add multiple "edit" or "update" sections, it makes the whole a lot harder to read. If anyone is interested in previous versions, those are still available.

Answer (score 1):

QThread is not a *Qt thread*, that is, it is not a new type of thread implemented by Qt but QThread is a **thread manager**, so only the code executed in the run method is executed in that secondary thread, everything else will be executed in the thread to which QThread belongs as QObject.

And if the QThread was created in the main thread then everything else will be.

So you have 2 options:

- override run method and there create the object of class "hardware", or
- Use moveToThread.

Second is best.

Comment: I have not subclassed  QThread (from what I read that is no longer recommended, particularly if using sig/slots in the thread).  So not called from 'run' .  But, since my first debug statement shows  running in thread #1, shouldn't any object I create IN that thread also run in thread #1?  That's where I'm getting confused

Comment: @TSG 1) precisely because it is not recommended to subclassify QThread I point out that the second option is the best (signals and slots have nothing to do with it since they will still work), 2) I could not point out about it since I need more information so yes you want more help then provide what has been asked of you: an MRE

Comment: I think I solved it based on your comment.  I'll post explanation above - but still unsure why works as described above.  Your answer as is doesn't quite fit the question now - but it definetely pointed my in the right direction

Comment: There is one problem with this answer: It causes lots of confusion, because it confuses threads and threads. One kind of thread is the actual (OS-provided) thread. The other is a `QThread` instance, which is not a thread but a C++ object that can be used to interact with a thread. It's similar to a `std::fstream`, which is not a file but can be used to interact with a file.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt My answer precisely explains that they are different things.